# Prefix of $wpdb does not worked and does not displayed

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I tried to show my prefix but I can't display it. It just shows a white page.

```
define( 'INVOICE', dirname(__FILE__) );
global $wpdb;
include INVOICE . '/invoice.php';
$id= $_GET['id'];
$table=$_GET['table'];
$query= "Select * from '$table' where id='$id'";
echo $wpdb->prefix;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prefix` is what adds "wp-" to a custom table. Are you trying to query a table and get results back?